# Express Session Not updating from route files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, mern

I am trying to create a book tracker with the MERN stack. I want to save some information in session, that is, when user tries to register, he hits a route, where validation happens and an email is sent to check if email really exists. Now the username, email, password and a verification code, are saved in session (which is actually not working), so that the verify route can access it, and save the user to database is the verification code entered by the user is correct which was sent to the email. Now saving of the information is not working, here is my code:

`app.js` file (entry point)

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import session from "express-session";
// import routes
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.js";

// db config
mongoose
  .connect(process.env.DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => console.log("DB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
// constants
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5001;

// middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
    proxy: true,
  })
);

// using routes
app.use("/api", authRoutes);

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}/`)
);
```

`routes/auth.js` (auth related routes)

```js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import express from "express";
import securePin from "secure-pin";
import { User } from "../models/user.js";
import { transporter } from "../config/nodemailer.js";

const router = express.Router();

function validateEmail(email) {
  return /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email);
}

router.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password } = req.body;

  //check email matches the pattern
  if (!validateEmail(email)) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Email is not valid",
    });
  }

  // check if email already exists
  User.findOne({ email: email }, (err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: "Email already exists, please sign in",
      });
    }
  });

  // check username is taken
  User.findOne({ username: username }, (err, user) => {
    if (user) {
      return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: "Username already exists, please choose another one",
      });
    }
  });

  // check username is atleast 4 characters
  if (username.length < 4) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Username must be atleast 4 characters",
    });
  }

  // check if username contains invalid characters
  if (username.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/)) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Username must not contain special characters or spaces",
    });
  }

  // check password contains spaces
  if (password.match(/\s/)) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Password must not contain spaces",
    });
  }

  // check password is atleast 6 characters
  if (password.length < 6) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Password must be atleast 6 characters",
    });
  }

  // generate unique token
  var charSet = new securePin.CharSet();
  charSet.addLowerCaseAlpha().addUpperCaseAlpha().addNumeric().randomize();
  const code = securePin.generateStringSync(6, charSet);

  // save info in session
  req.session.username = username;
  req.session.email = email;
  req.session.password = password;
  req.session.code = code;
  req.session.save();

  // send token to user's email
  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    to: email,
    subject: "no reply- book tracker confirmation",
    text: `Your verification code is: ${code}.`,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.json({
        status: "error",
        message: err.message.toString(),
      });
    }
    return res.json({
      status: "success",
      message: "Email sent",
    });
  });
});

router.post("/register/verify", (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.body;
  const { username, email, password } = req.session;

  // check if code matches
  if (code !== req.session.code) {
    return res.json({
      status: "error",
      message: "Code is invalid",
    });
  }

  // create user
  const user = new User({
    username,
    email,
    password,
  });

  // save user
  // user.save((err) => {
  //   if (err) {
  //     return res.json({
  //       status: "error",
  //       message: err.message,
  //     });
  //   }
  //   return res.json({
  //     status: "success",
  //     message: "Account created successfully!",
  //   });
  // });

  console.log(user);
  return res.json(user);
});

export default router;
```